# java.lang.ClassCastException on some devices

Tags: java, android

Google Developer Console indicates me that my app got `java.lang.ClassCastException`  error on 2 different devices (`P10 (HWVTR)-Android 7.0` and `LG G3 (g3) - Android 6.0`) at the same lane. I don't know what's the problem, I have tested it on `Samsung Galaxy A3 2014 & 2017 and Huawei P9 Lite` and works great.

Here is the code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "toast", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    final int hasVisited = prefs.getInt("HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE", 0);

    if(hasVisited == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }
        builder.setTitle("My Text")
                .setMessage("My Text, dsajh jghjsahjhsda dsa dsa")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .show();
        prefs.edit().putInt("HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE", 1).apply();
    }
```

The error is here `final int hasVisited = prefs.getInt("HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE", 0);`

I want to display this `AlertDialog` only once when the app if run for the first time.

Error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
  at com.doggedness_dev.pubgcratessimulator.MenuActivity.onCreate (MenuActivity.java:40)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6272)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
```

It is possible that my SharedPreferences with the key `HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE` to interfere with another app that has the same key?

Comment: try commit() instead of apply() `prefs.edit().putInt("HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE", 1).commit();` because `commit()` writes the data synchronously (blocking the thread its called from). It then informs you about the success of the operation.
`apply()` schedules the data to be written asynchronously. It does not inform you about the success of the operation.

Comment: Ok. I will change, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every application has their own shared preferences location, so there is no way to interfere with another app that has the same key.

If your application's older versions have the same key with `HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE` and its value is not integer, you will have this problem. Because you have already have the value for this key and types are just different.

You can use try-catch like below, for this exception.

```
try {

}catch (ClassCastException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are right! My older version used `SharedPreferences` with boolean `false and true` to determinate if the app is running for the first time, only in the latest version I changed it to an integer. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @MoisoniIonut you're welcome. Alternatively, you can change the key 'HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE' for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    }
```

and write below line;

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```